# Internal joins in R

Tags: r

How do get data in R for large set of data?

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = c(A,A,B,B,B,"","","","","","",), 
col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4,2,5,4,7,1,2,3)),  
col3=c(5,6,7,10,15,15,10,20,30,40,50))
```

where
col3=sale number
output result:
From col2 select those row which are not assigned with col1 ex.
col2 row 1,2 which is assigned with A from col1, so I want sale number of col3 excluding which is present in A i.e. 5 & 6 from col3,

similarly, 3,4,2 assigned with B from col1, so I want sale number of col3 excluding which is present in B i.e. 7,10,15 from col3.

```
Expected result:

    col1         col2                      col3(SUM OF SALE)
    A             1                                30
    A             2                                40
    B             3                                50
    B             4                                10
    B             2                                 6
    B             2                                 40
```

Comment: The example does not work.

Comment: Hi, can you able to answer now for the edited example? @AndreWildberg

Comment: `data` still does not work.